# performance of allocatable vs. statically sized arrays

Tags: fortran

I have a fortran code I had to modify to include a new library. Initially in the code the size of an array was passed in the Makefile, which meant every time I wanted to change the size of array I had to recompile the code. I changed this to read the size of the input array from an "input parameters file" so that it avoids the need to recompile every time. However, due to various reasons, my code is much slower than before.

Talking to my boss, he was of the opinion it might be possible that because we are not passing the size of the array during compile time, the code is not well optimized. Is it possibly true?

Thanks

---------------Edit---------------------

Initially there were these line in the makefile

```
NL    = 8
@echo Making $(SIZE_FILE) .....
echo "      integer, parameter( nl = " $(NL) " )" > $(SIZE_FILE)
```

This created a "sizefile" with value of "NL". This file was "include"d in the main program at as the header and then arrays were declared like this in the fortran file:

```
 include "sizefile"
 real*8, dimension   ur(nl)
```

Now I have declared a subroutine called "read_input_parameters" which is called by the program which reads a text file with the value of "Nl". And then I allocate the array like this:

```
  program   test

  integer n
  allocatable :: ur(:)

  call  read_input_parameters(n)

  allocate(ur(n))

  *operations*

  deallocate(ur)
  stop
  end
```

Comment: It's *possible*, but you will have to show how you are now allocating your arrays vs. how it was done before.  Without seeing your code, it's impossible to know if it's not well optimized or for us to point you in ways to potentially fix your issue.

Comment: Also, you should probably change the title of this post to describe the problem.  "Arguments inside Makefile" is not your real issue, it's performance of allocatable vs. statically sized arrays.

Comment: what os and how big is the allocation?  Sounds like maybe you are forcing page swapping.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a profiler and find the operations that are slow and post their code. The code you showed is useless. Are the results correct, at least?

The slowness can be caused by many factors. One of them is bad argument passing, which makes copy-in / copy-out necessary. Also, the fact that the subroutine does not know if the array is contiguous can do some harm, but not much.

Comment: thanks! the code give correct results. this subroutine is called only once in the beginning of a program and takes less than a second to run. The whole code runs after for days. i will look into the profiler.